# How to pass constants to a function which is used in fminbnd(@myfun,x1,x2) in a loop

Tags: matlab

I'm implementing a ML receiver for a communication channel. 
For this I need to find the minimum value of the function below with respect to `x` in the range `x = 0 to 15` (16QAM)

```
f = abs( rx(n) - (h'*h)*x )^2 ;
```

I have to iterate this in a loop (`n=1:100`). I found that I can do this by matlab function  `x = fminbnd(fun,x1,x2)` where I can put the function in a separate .m-file as:

```
function f = myfun(x)  
f = abs( rx(n) - (h'*h)*x )^2
```

and find the minimum for `x` from

```
x = fminbnd(@myfun,x1,x2);
```

My question is since constants to the function `rx(n)` is changing thorough the loop, how to sent it to the function `myfun(x)` within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using an anonymous function to call your function in a separate file:

```
function mainfcnmin
    h = [1;1];
    rx = 1:3;

    for n = 1:length(rx)
        x = fminbnd(@(x)myfun(x,rx(n),h),0,15)
    end
end

function f = myfun(x,rx,h)
    f = abs(rx-(h'*h)*x)^2 ;
end
```

---

Or alternatively in **one file** by defining the function directly in the anonymous function like this:

```
h = [1;1];
rx = 1:3;

for n = 1:length(rx)
    x = fminbnd(@(x)(abs(rx(n)-(h'*h)*x)^2),0,15)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a function with rx(n) as a second parameter and then turn it into a single parameter anonymous function inside the loop.

Here is an example from the MATLAB documentation (for 'fminsearch' function):

> If fun is parameterized, you can use anonymous functions to capture
>   the problem-dependent parameters. For example, suppose you want to
>   minimize the objective function myfun defined by the following
>   function file:

```
function f = myfun(x,a)
    f = x(1)^2 + a*x(2)^2;`
```

> Note that myfun has an extra parameter a, so you cannot pass it directly to > fminsearch. To optimize for a specific value of a, such as a = 1.5.
>
> 1. Assign the value to a
>
>    > `a = 1.5; % define parameter first`
> 2. Call
>      fminsearch with a one-argument anonymous function that captures that
>      value of a and calls myfun with two arguments:
>
>    ```
>    x = fminsearch(@(x) myfun(x,a),[0,1])
>    ```

Hope that helped (sorry for bad text formatting).